# cannot disable ajax calls in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm attempting to disable ajax calls for hyperlinks on pages within a given site.  I have researched the jquery mobile documentation and other questions here.  I *think* this is the correct code, in the correct order.  but it's not working.  Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

```
<script src="/cmsroot/jquery-ui-mobile/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>  
    $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.extend( $.mobile , {
        ajaxEnabled: false;
        pushStateEnabled: false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="/cmsroot/jquery-ui-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i thing you should change the order of script. Refer jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js right after jquery..

Comment: The documentation says jquery.js, then bind, then jquery.mobile.  I did try to re-order, just for giggles, but ajax still being called.  "Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. Link to your JavaScript files in the following order:

    
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>"

Comment: does that need to wrap in dom ready? I'm not familier with jquery-mobile though

Comment: According to jquery.mobile:  "Unlike other jQuery projects, such as jQuery and jQuery UI, jQuery Mobile automatically applies many markup enhancements as soon as it loads (long before the document.ready event fires). "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  My first problem was that I was accidentally looking at the wrong documentation set (jquery.mobile 1.2 instead of 1.4).  Secondly, I had syntax problem:  semicolon instead of comma after each option.  Corrected code is

```
<script src="/cmsroot/jquery-ui-mobile/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.extend( $.mobile , {
        ajaxEnabled: false,
        pushStateEnabled: false
        });
    });

  </script>
<script src="/cmsroot/jquery-ui-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```